# A way to search SQL to only pull rows of data that ONLY HAS null value

Tags: sql-server, optimization, null, case, row

This is my query:

```
SELECT patientname, patientID, 
 (CASE WHEN patientID is not null THEN 'yes'
             WHEN CpatientID is null then 'No'    
        END) as submittedintohospital

FROM dbo].[database](nolock)
and patientname = "John Smith"
```

this is data result:

```
PatientName                     PatientID
John Smith     12345488999       NULL
John Smith     12880889976       NULL
```

As you can see, a patient have 2 rows of result, and I want to set a condition where only ALL the rows
's patientID is null, then it will go into case for yes.

Because currently query I wrote it will show patient data with both null and non-null value:

For example:

```
John Wick   1895
John Wick   NULL
```

I want to eliminate that and only pull patient name where all the rows must have null patientID, not just one row.

Comment: Stop [splattering nolock everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to set a condition where only ALL the rows 's patientID is null, then it will go into case for yes.

You can use window functions:

```
select patientname, patientid, 
    case when max(patientid) over(partition by patientname) is null     
        then 'yes'
        else 'no'    
    end as submittedintohospital
from [dbo].[database]
```

If you want to actually filter the results:

```
select patientname, patientid
from (
    select d.*, 
        max(patientid) over(partition by patientname) max_patientid
    from [dbo].[database] d
) d
where max_patientid is null
```

`not exists` might also come handy for filtering:

```
select d.*
from [dbo].[database] d
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from [dbo].[database] d1
    where d1.patientname = d.patientname and d1.patientid is not null
)
```

Comment: Hey I'm doing join on another database, there are some syntax error now, can you take  a look?

Comment: @GBM hey cna you look at new question I posted?